How to Asynchronously Send Chunked Data from call_tool_with_selection via WebSocket in Python?
I'm working on an asynchronous Python project where I need to execute a selected tool through call_tool_with_selection() and send its output over a WebSocket connection in real-time.
I'm encountering some issues when trying to stream the chunked response from the tool's output (response_gen) via WebSocket. I would like to stream the chunks from the generator and send them as part of a WebSocket message to the client. Below is the code snippet that I've written so far:
response_generator = call_tool_with_selection(tool_calls[0], tools, verbose=True)

message = ''
try:
    if hasattr(response_generator.raw_output, "response_gen"):
        async for chunk in response_generator.raw_output.response_gen:
            message += chunk
            # logger.info("SOCKET SEND:")
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                "message": message,
                "conversation_id": conversation_id,
                "type": "message"
            }))
    else:
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            "message": await self.send(response_generator.content),
            "conversation_id": conversation_id,
            "type": "message"
        }))
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)


Here, The async for loop over response_generator.raw_output.response_gen doesn't seem to work as expected. It either doesn't print or send any chunks, or throws an error.
